# Concisely give priority to non-Prelude functions in ghci

Tags: haskell, text, ghci, haskell-prelude

I have the following imports:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric,  OverloadedStrings,  DefaultSignatures,  TypeOperators,  FlexibleContexts, RecordWildCards, FlexibleInstances, ExtendedDefaultRules #-}

import qualified Data.Map as Map
import qualified Data.Set as Set
import Data.Text
import GHC.Generics
import Data.DateTime
import Data.Aeson
```

I try to use the function `lines` to break on newline, and this function exists in both `Prelude` and `Data.Text`, and I get the following:

```
$ stack ghci
Prelude> :set -XOverloadedStrings
Prelude> :l mydat.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( mydat.hs, interpreted )

mydat.hs:39:13: error:
    Ambiguous occurrence ‘lines’
    It could refer to either ‘Prelude.lines’,
                             imported from ‘Prelude’ at mydat.hs:1:1
                             (and originally defined in ‘base-4.11.1.0:Data.OldList’)
                          or ‘Data.Text.lines’,
                             imported from ‘Data.Text’ at mydat.hs:7:1-16
   |
39 |     print $ lines text
   |             ^^^^^
Failed, no modules loaded.
```

It's clear from the error message that this is failing because `lines` exists in both `Prelude` and `Data.Text.lines`.

What I'd like is to tell ghci to take /any/ function imported besides Prelude over
any function defined in Prelude, particularly with text.

I thought one way to do this would be to explicitly, selectively hide `Prelude.lines`:

```
$ stack ghci
Prelude> :set -XOverloadedStrings -XNoImplicitPrelude
Prelude> import Prelude hiding (lines)
Prelude> :l mydat.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( mydat.hs, interpreted )

mydat.hs:13:23: error:
    Not in scope: type constructor or class ‘Float’
    Perhaps you meant ‘UFloat’ (imported from GHC.Generics)
```

But this doesn't seem feasible: if I try to just hide one prelude function, I lose all the other functions I actually want.

What's the right way to keep `Data.Text` functions and hide them from  collisions with `Prelude.*`?  Am I stuck name-spacing everything with

```
import Data.Text as T
```

And using, for example:

```
T.lines
```

?

If so, that seems a bit cumbersome, and would suggest making a Prelude package that is essentially PreludeWithoutPreludeText loading all the rest except this one--given the utility of `OverloadedStrings`.

Comment: That `import Prelude hiding (lines)` statement needs to be inside your `mydat.hs` file, not in ghci.

Comment: What you're supposed to do is namespace `Data.Text`. Sometimes I find myself using the same functions from `Data.List`, `Data.Text`, `Data.Text.Lazy`, `Data.ByteString`, and/or `Data.ByteString.Lazy`, and by far the easiest way to deal with all of this is to just namespace everything. This also makes it much clearer where your `lines` came from to anyone else reading your code (most people expect common prelude functions to be from prelude unless they're namespaced).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible (speaking about GHC 8.6.4).

One thing you may do is to qualify `Prelude` instead:

```
import qualified Prelude
```

optionally `as P`, which will require you to explicitly type `Prelude.` (or `P.`) before any name from this library.

If you use other `Prelude` functions frequently you may hide only colliding identifiers by writing

```
import Prelude hiding (lines)
```

which will remove `Prelude.lines` from the namespace.

If you want to use `lines` from `Prelude` somewhere in the file anyway, you could import this particular identifier as qualified:

```
import           Prelude hiding (lines)
import qualified Prelude as P (lines)
```

I am afraid that it is everything you can do.